# Where can I get the image of the installation disc that came installed (mountain lion)?

Tags: macos, restore

If I open the App Store, I can see the OS X Mountain Lion with a price and not "installed" or something like that. I don't want to pay for the OS that is already installed by default. Isn't there a way to download the image, an utility to create it or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no DVD for Mountain Lion. Since Lion arrived with the App Store as a digital release, the core OS is not something you re-download from the store. You don't need to pay to re-download, but you do have to go through the Recovery HD to initiate the download.

When you buy an upgrade from Snow Leopard to Lion or an upgrade to Mountain Lion - that installer can be re-downloaded, but when the OS is included with a CPU purchase, you don't need to have an Apple ID or account to re-download the OS. You just enter recovery mode and run the installer. It downloads the package after verifying eligibility by checking the serial number on the Mac hardware.

If you interrupt the process, you can grab the installer from the drive - but it's not something that the system was designed to deliver to you as a downloadable package. It was designed to download and re-install on an "as-needed" basis without needing an account, a password - just an internet connection and some time to wait for the download.

Comment: Just to add to this, you can create an external recovery disk using Apple's own Recovery Disk Assistant - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4848

Comment: That recovery disk simply replaces the internet recovery (boot image) and doesn't have the installer packages downloaded. It is nice to have a second drive to boot and run Disk Utility or be able to truly zero/repartition the internal drive. I also have been warned to not depend on that as it has not been updated since August 2011 and the recovery isn't a universal boot - just a custom boot for the Mac model from whence it came.

Comment: True.  Really there isn't replacement for the good ol' external bootable drive of past, with a fully loaded OS and whatever diagnostic software & images you might need.

Comment: I have a pair of [SDXC cards](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sdxc) with downloaded images, bootable OS, other goodies on them and am quite happy with not needing to lug HDD around anymore.